# How can I know if html element is on the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need know if element is on the sreen, or is it off the screen. How can I do that with jQuery ? For example if my element is out of screen it has attribute top: 3000px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to do but probabily there's a better way to do it.

Anyhow, you can see the position of the element and compare with the window boundaries.

Check this links to see how to do it:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
- http://danielbrolund.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/getting-html-element-screen-position/

Answer (score 3):

$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

If $(window).height(); is less than 3000px than your element is offscreen!

Comment: You also need to check the scroll position using $(window).scrollTop()